# Unexpected error while using create-react-app to create a react. (Error: spawn UNKNOWN)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have installed the prerequisites for react application but I get this error repeatedly.
[The image attached represents the error I faced while using][1] `npx create-react-app myapp`

Error:

````
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\user\Downloads\New folder\react_sample-main\myapp.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:390:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at install (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:341:10)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:468:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myapp/ from C:\Users\user\Downloads\New folder\react_sample-main
Done. ```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X01ul.jpg
````

Comment: `node v16.14.0` and `npm 8.3.1`